# Build series of datetimes with exclusions in Elixir

Tags: datetime, functional-programming, elixir

I would like to generate a list of available time slots between two dates whilst removing time slots that are booked.

Firstly, there is a list of `time_slots` which are tuples of `{start_time, end_time}` and are available to be booked on any given day:

```
time_slots = [
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[13:00:00]},
  {~T[13:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
  {~T[17:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]}
]
```

Then there is a list of `bookings`, which contain tuples of `{booking_start, booking_end}`:

```
bookings = [
  {~N[2019-06-14 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-14 17:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-15 13:00:00Z]},
  # some bookings may sit outside a slot range
  {~N[2019-06-16 15:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-16 21:00:00Z]}
]
```

There is also a tuple containing the `{start_date, end_date}` that we would like to generate all the available time slots between.

```
start_end = {~N[2019-06-13 01:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-16 23:00:00Z]}
```

In this case we would want to generate all the available time slots, and return:

```
available_slots = [
  {~N[2019-06-13 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-13 13:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-13 13:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-14 17:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-14 21:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 13:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-15 17:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 17:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-15 21:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-16 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-16 13:00:00Z]}
]
```

- For a time slot to be taken it would require either a booking’s start or finish to overlap inside of it (regardless of how small that overlap is):

  - *e.g. a booking of 0900–1000 would fill the 0900–1300, 0900–1700 and 0900–2100 time slots*
- A time slot can be filled with more than one booking:

  - *e.g. we can have bookings of 0900–1000 and 1000–1200, which would both fit inside the 0900–1300 time slot.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, paste the code in a file `timeslots.exs` and run with `elixir timeslots.exs`.

The steps taken are:

1. Build a list of all available time_slots that fit within start_end
2. Remove the slots that have overlap with a booking

The `has_overlap?` check was a bit tricky, might need some more testing. It also removes an *eclipsed* slot, when the booking_start is before and the booking_end is after the slot.

```
defmodule TimeSlots do
  def available_time_slots(bookings, time_slots, start_end) do
    time_slots_in_range(time_slots, start_end)
    |> remove_booked_slots(bookings)
  end

  # Build a list with all time_slots between start_date_time and end_date_time
  defp time_slots_in_range(time_slots, {start_date_time, end_date_time}) do
    start_date = NaiveDateTime.to_date(start_date_time)
    end_date = NaiveDateTime.to_date(end_date_time)

    Date.range(start_date, end_date)
    |> Enum.map(fn date -> daily_time_slots(date, time_slots) end)
    |> List.flatten
    |> Enum.filter(fn {slot_start_date_time, slot_end_date_time} ->
      NaiveDateTime.compare(start_date_time, slot_start_date_time) != :gt &&
      NaiveDateTime.compare(end_date_time, slot_end_date_time) != :lt
    end)
  end

  defp daily_time_slots(date, time_slots) do
    Enum.map(time_slots, &(create_time_slot(date, &1)))
  end

  defp create_time_slot(date, {start_time, end_time}) do
    {:ok, start_date_time} = NaiveDateTime.new(date, start_time)
    {:ok, end_date_time} = NaiveDateTime.new(date, end_time)
    {start_date_time, end_date_time}
  end

  defp remove_booked_slots(time_slots, bookings) do
    Enum.reject(time_slots, fn time_slot ->
      Enum.reduce(bookings, false, fn booking, acc ->
        acc or has_overlap?(booking, time_slot)
      end)
    end)
  end

  # (slot_start <= booking_start < slot_end)
  # or (slot_start < booking_end <= slot_end)
  # or (booking_start <= slot_start and slot_end <= booking_end)
  defp has_overlap?({booking_start, booking_end}, {slot_start, slot_end}) do
    (NaiveDateTime.compare(slot_start, booking_start) != :gt &&
     NaiveDateTime.compare(booking_start, slot_end) == :lt) ||
    (NaiveDateTime.compare(slot_start, booking_end) == :lt &&
     NaiveDateTime.compare(booking_end, slot_end) != :gt) ||
    (NaiveDateTime.compare(booking_start, slot_start) != :gt &&
     NaiveDateTime.compare(slot_end, booking_end) != :gt)
  end
end


time_slots = [
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[13:00:00]},
  {~T[13:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
  {~T[17:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]}
]

bookings = [
  {~N[2019-06-14 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-14 17:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-15 13:00:00Z]},
  # some bookings may sit outside a slot range
  {~N[2019-06-16 15:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-16 21:00:00Z]}
]

# I've changed the end date to 2019-06-16 to match the expected result
start_end = {~N[2019-06-13 01:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-16 23:00:00Z]}

available_slots = [
  {~N[2019-06-13 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-13 13:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-13 13:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-14 17:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-14 21:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 13:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-15 17:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 17:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-15 21:00:00Z]},
  {~N[2019-06-16 09:00:00Z], ~N[2019-06-16 13:00:00Z]}
]

# Test it
IO.inspect TimeSlots.available_time_slots(bookings, time_slots, start_end)
```

Should give the correct result:

```
[
  {~N[2019-06-13 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 13:00:00]},
  {~N[2019-06-13 13:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00]},
  {~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00]},
  {~N[2019-06-14 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-14 21:00:00]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 13:00:00], ~N[2019-06-15 17:00:00]},
  {~N[2019-06-15 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-15 21:00:00]},
  {~N[2019-06-16 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-16 13:00:00]}
]
```